# SQL Server Left Outer Join returns either too many rows or incorrect rows

Tags: sql-server, left-join, multiple-tables

I have a SQL Server query that I want to do a left join to 2 tables.  I need it to return all of the rows in the 1st table and only the matching data in the other 2 tables.  My first incarnation created some sort of cross product with more than 10 times the required rows.  So I added a rowcount function and had it filter for all rowcount values = 1.  Now it returns the correct number of rows but with the wrong data from the other 2 tables.

I have certain filter rules (case statements) I apply to the contents of the 2 right tables to determine what, if anything, to return.  I think this may be the source of the problem, but I'm not sure.  I've tried using the filter code both within the select statement and as a where statement at the end of the query and even as part of the join on statement.  I also tried using cross and outer applies. All to no avail.

I'm trying to achieve this without using loops.  Is it possible?  Please see the code below.  This code generates too many rows.  I won't repeat the 2nd iteration as it adds an extra select on top and a filter for m= 1 to the bottom to generate the correct number of rows.

These are the 2 tables that I am left joining to.  Note that the 2nd table is only a small subset of a much larger table.

Thanks!!!

```
SELECT
GLENTRY.Fac + GLENTRY.Rundt + GLENTRY.Jrnllog AS UniqueID,
GLENTRY.Fac AS Fac,
(CASE WHEN 
    EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd <> '' AND EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd = SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,6,3)
THEN 
    EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
ELSE
    CASE WHEN
        EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd <> 0 AND EntityTranslate2014.Acct = GLENTRY.Acct
    THEN 
        EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN 
            EntityTranslate2014.SSDept <> 0 AND EntityTranslate2014.SSDept = SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,1,4)
        THEN 
            EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN 
                EntityTranslate2014.SSDept = 0
                AND
                EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd = ''
                AND
                EntityTranslate2014.Acct = 0 
            THEN 
                EntityTranslate2014.Entity
            ELSE
                '' 
            END
        END
    END
END)
AS NEWEntity,

(CASE WHEN AcctTranslate2014.Fac = GLENTRY.Fac OR AcctTranslate2014.Fac = '0' 
THEN 
    AcctTranslate2014.NEWDept 
ELSE 
    Null 
END)
AS Department,

(CONVERT(DATETIME,GLENTRY.Period + '/01/' + 
                        CASE WHEN 
                            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),GLENTRY.Yearz) = '' 
                        THEN 
                            '2014' 
                        ELSE 
                            GLENTRY.Yearz
                        END) 
AS YEARPER,

GLENTRY.Acct) AS SSAcct,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),
            CASE WHEN 
                AcctTranslate2014.Fac = GLENTRY.Fac OR AcctTranslate2014.Fac = '0'
            THEN 
                AcctTranslate2014.NEWAcct 
            ELSE 
                Null 
            END)
AS NEWAccount,
GLENTRY.Rundt,
GLENTRY.Jrnlid,
GLENTRY.Amount,
GLENTRY.Dc,
GLENTRY.Ref,
GLENTRY.Refdt,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),'Import of SS ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),GLENTRY.Period) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),GLENTRY.Yearz) + ' GL activity') AS Descr,
GLENTRY.Invnr,
GLENTRY.Jrnllog,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GLENTRY.Fac, GLENTRY.Yearz, GLENTRY.Period, GLENTRY.Pagez, GLENTRY.Acct, GLENTRY.Rundt, GLENTRY.Jrnlid,
GLENTRY.Amount, GLENTRY.Dc, GLENTRY.Ref, GLENTRY.Refdt, GLENTRY.Descr, GLENTRY.Invnr, GLENTRY.Origfac, GLENTRY.Jrnllog, GLENTRY.Seq
ORDER BY GLENTRY.Fac, GLENTRY.Yearz, GLENTRY.Period) AS m

FROM GLENTRY 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    EntityTranslate2014 ON GLENTRY.Fac = EntityTranslate2014.Fac 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AcctTranslate2014 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GLENTRY.Acct) = AcctTranslate2014.SSAcct
WHERE GLENTRY.Yearz = 2014 AND GLENTRY.Period = 11


EntityTranslate2014 File

Fac Entity  Descr       AcctEnd SSDept  Acct
1   51900   Entity1     0               0
2   50901   Entity2     0               0
3   10100   Entity3     0               0
3   10500   Entity4     4016            0
3   10500   Entity4     4020            0
3   10500   Entity4     4022            0
3   10500   Entity4     4024            0
3   10500   Entity4     4028            0
3   10500   Entity4     7016            0
4   30900   Entity5     0               0
5   10300   Entity6     0               0
6   11300   Entity7     0               0
7   11100   Entity8     0               0
7   11500   Entity9     4016            0
7   11500   Entity9     4020            0
7   11500   Entity9     4022            0
7   11500   Entity9     4024            0
7   11500   Entity9     4028            0
7   11500   Entity9     7016            0
9   32909   Entity10    0               0
10  12100   Entity11    0               0
11  32901   Entity12    0               0
12  53900   Entity13    0               0
13  10200   Entity14    0               0
14  32914   Entity15    0               0
15  32915   Entity16    0               0
16  11200   Entity17    0               0
17  32917   Entity18    0               0
18  32918   Entity19    0               0
19  32919   Entity20    0               0
20  32920   Entity21    0               0
21  13100   Entity22    0               0
22  52900   Entity23    0               0
89  99900   Entity24    0               0
123 12300   Entity25    0               0
124 12200   Entity26    0               0
133 13300   Entity27    0               0
201 11201   Entity28    0               0
202 11202   Entity29    0               0
402 25402   Entity30    0               0
403 25403   Entity31    0               0
549 25430   Entity32    0               0
549 25432   Entity33    7195            0
910 50910   Entity34    0               0
911 50911   Entity35    0               0
21  13500   Entity36    4016            0
21  13500   Entity36    4020            0
21  13500   Entity36    4022            0
21  13500   Entity36    4024            0
21  13500   Entity36    4028            0
21  13500   Entity36    7016            0
16  11202   Entity37    0        002    0
16  11201   Entity37    0        001    0
16  11200   Entity38    0               30918000
16  11200   Entity38    0               31918000
16  11200   Entity38    0               32110000


AcctTranslate2014

NewAcct     SSAcct      NewDEpt Fac
10111500    111200010   000     0
10111600    111200050   000     0
10111700    111550010   000     0
10113092    111050450   000     0
10115090    111050010   000     0
```

Comment: Is the relationship between GLENTRY and EntityTranslate2014 1-to-1 or 1-to-many? If the relationship if 1-to-many then that explains why you're results are being duplicated. It's hard to determine without a better understanding of the data. Perhaps you could provide some sample data.

Comment: The left outer join sounds like the way to go.  Is that the code you have posted?  A quick check is that the outer join only refers to the source table, and not to the two tables that could return null.

Comment: I have added the 2 tables I am left joining to.  Note the 2nd table only shows a few of 100's of rows.

Comment: rhholt and Brian J - Thanks for your quick replies!                              The relationship between GLENTRY and EntityTranslate2014 can be many to many. That is the purpose of the Case logic in the select statement, although I think it may not be effective enough.  I'm using it to return the correct row from the EntityTranslate2014 table.   As to the left joins, I have 2 left join statements at the bottom of the query.  Are they incorrect?  Is there a special way to left join GLENTRY to both EntityTranslate2014 and AcctTranslate2014?

Answer (score 1):

Updated...

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to count sequences in the joined results, and `ORDER BY` to sort them so that the row you want is first in that sequence.

Thank you for posting the loop construct, I think I was able to approximate it's function with a series of CTEs(WITH alias as (...)).  I'm not sure that I got all your table/field names correct, but this should be close to functional.  A major guess on my part was how the "first" entity should be determined, you may need to tune the order by in the row number functions in the CTEs.

```
WITH ENTFIND AS (
    SELECT  
        EntityTranslate2014.Fac,
        EntityTranslate2014.Acct,
        EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd,
        EntityTranslate2014.Entity,
        EntityTranslate2014.SSDept,
        EntityTranslate2014.Entity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd ORDER BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd, Entity) as E1Sort
    FROM
        EntityTranslate2014
),
E2 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd ORDER BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd, Entity) as E2Sort
    FROM
        ENTFIND
    WHERE
        AcctEnd <> 0
),
E3 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd ORDER BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd, Entity) as E3Sort
    FROM
        ENTFIND
    WHERE
        SSDept <> 0
),
E4 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd ORDER BY Fac, Acct, AcctEnd, Entity) as E4Sort
    FROM
        ENTFIND
    WHERE
        Acct = 0
        AND
        AcctEnd = ''
        AND
        SSDept = 0
)
SELECT
    GLENTRY.Fac + GLENTRY.Rundt + GLENTRY.Jrnllog AS UniqueID,
    GLENTRY.Fac AS Fac,,
    E1.Entity,
    E2.Entity,
    E3.Entity,
    E4.Entity,
    COALESCE(E1.Entity,E2.Entity,E3.Entity,E4.Entity) as 1stFoundEntity,
(CASE WHEN 
    EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd <> '' AND EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd = SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,6,3)
THEN 
    EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
ELSE
    CASE WHEN
        EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd <> 0 AND EntityTranslate2014.Acct = GLENTRY.Acct
    THEN 
        EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN 
            EntityTranslate2014.SSDept <> 0 AND EntityTranslate2014.SSDept = SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,1,4)
        THEN 
            EntityTranslate2014.Entity 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN 
                EntityTranslate2014.SSDept = 0
                AND
                EntityTranslate2014.AcctEnd = ''
                AND
                EntityTranslate2014.Acct = 0 
            THEN 
                EntityTranslate2014.Entity
            ELSE
                '' 
            END
        END
    END
END)
AS NEWEntity,

(CASE WHEN AcctTranslate2014.Fac = GLENTRY.Fac OR AcctTranslate2014.Fac = '0' 
THEN 
    AcctTranslate2014.NEWDept 
ELSE 
    Null 
END)
AS Department,

(CONVERT(DATETIME,GLENTRY.Period + '/01/' + 
                        CASE WHEN 
                            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),GLENTRY.Yearz) = '' 
                        THEN 
                            '2014' 
                        ELSE 
                            GLENTRY.Yearz
                        END) 
AS YEARPER,

GLENTRY.Acct) AS SSAcct,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),
            CASE WHEN 
                AcctTranslate2014.Fac = GLENTRY.Fac OR AcctTranslate2014.Fac = '0'
            THEN 
                AcctTranslate2014.NEWAcct 
            ELSE 
                Null 
            END) AS NEWAccount,
    GLENTRY.Rundt,
    GLENTRY.Jrnlid,
    GLENTRY.Amount,
    GLENTRY.Dc,
    GLENTRY.Ref,
    GLENTRY.Refdt,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),'Import of SS ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),GLENTRY.Period) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),GLENTRY.Yearz) + ' GL activity') AS Descr,
    GLENTRY.Invnr,
    GLENTRY.Jrnllog,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GLENTRY.Fac, GLENTRY.Yearz, GLENTRY.Period, GLENTRY.Pagez, GLENTRY.Acct,         GLENTRY.Rundt, GLENTRY.Jrnlid,
        GLENTRY.Amount, GLENTRY.Dc, GLENTRY.Ref, GLENTRY.Refdt, GLENTRY.Descr, GLENTRY.Invnr, GLENTRY.Origfac,          GLENTRY.Jrnllog, GLENTRY.Seq
    ORDER BY GLENTRY.Fac, GLENTRY.Yearz, GLENTRY.Period) AS m
FROM
    GLENTRY
    LEFT JOIN 
        ENTFIND E1 ON GLENTRY.Fac = E1.Fac
                AND SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,6,3) = E1.AcctEnd
                    AND E1Sort = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
        E2 ON GLENTRY.Fac = E2.Fac
                AND GLENTRY.Acct = E2.Acct
                    AND E2.E2Sort = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
        E3 ON GLENTRY.Fac = E3.Fac
                AND SUBSTRING(GLENTRY.Acct,1,4) = E3.SSDept
                    AND E3.E3Sort = 1
    LEFT JOIN 
        E4 ON GLENTRY.Fac = E4.Fac
                AND E4.E4Sort = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
            EntityTranslate2014 ON GLENTRY.Fac = EntityTranslate2014.Fac 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
            AcctTranslate2014 ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GLENTRY.Acct) = AcctTranslate2014.SSAcct
WHERE 
    GLENTRY.Yearz = 2014 AND GLENTRY.Period = 11
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to filter for the correct row.  It won't be the same number each time.  That's why I am using the Case logic, albeit incorrectly I am guessing.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM GLENTRY
LEFT OUTER JOIN EntityTranslate2014
    ON GLENTRY.Fac = EntityTranslate2014.Fac
LEFT OUTER JOIN AcctTranslate2014
    ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GLENTRY.Acct) = AcctTranslate2014.SSAcct
```

There's no relation defined between `EntityTranslate2014` and `AcctTranslate2014`.  If there's more than one record in either table for the corresponding record in `GLENTRY`, then those two tables will effectively cross-join with each other.  For example, if a single `GLENTRY` joins to two records in `EntityTranslate2014` and two records in `AcctTranslate2014`, then you'll get 4 records, one for each possible combination.  That's simply how `JOIN` is defined.

If you know that this is happening and you know there's actually no relation, and you just want, say, for each record in `GLENTRY` the first record in `EntityTranslate2014` to match to the first record in `AcctTranslate2014`, and the second record in `EntityTranslate2014` to match to the second record in `AcctTranslate2014` and so on, you can do what I've heard called a "ZIP JOIN":

```
FROM GLENTRY
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Fac ORDER BY <SomeField>) row_order
        FROM EntityTranslate2014) ET2014
    ON GLENTRY.Fac = ET2014.Fac
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SSAcct ORDER BY <SomeField>) row_order
        FROM AcctTranslate2014) AT2014
    ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GLENTRY.Acct) = AT2014.SSAcct
    AND AT2014.row_order = ET2014.row_order
```

Obviously, don't use `SELECT *`; this is just an example.  So, what this is doing is assigning *some* order to each OUTER table, and them matching them up with each other.  Thus, each record in each OUTER table will only show up once.  If there's a mis-match, then the records from the other table will appear as `NULL`s.

The other common alternative is to simply return the first record for each OUTER table, so that you're guaranteed to only have one `GLENTRY` record since each OUTER table only contributes one or zero records for each key field.

If that *doesn't* work for your purposes, then you'll probably need to use two queries, and will need to do the matching in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I just uploaded some pseudo code of what I am trying to achieve.  There is no application to massage the data.  This query will be called by SSIS as part of a larger package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Correlated Subquery to "loop" through each row in one table comparing it to rows in another table without actually writing loop logic (which should be avoided in SQL). The rows in the inner query are compared to each row in the outer query based on the where predicate. Correlated Subqueries also allow you to filter the WHERE clause by the TOP 1 if more than 1 record would be returned in the WHERE clause query (as in the code below). This is just a brief example, as I don't have time to write out the code in its entirety, but it may help.

```
SELECT Entity
  FROM EntityTranslate2014 ent
 WHERE ent.AcctEnd <> ''
   AND AcctEnd = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(glt.Acct,6,3) 
                    FROM Glentry glt 
                   WHERE glt.fac = ent.fac
                     AND glt.Year = 2014
                     AND glt.Period = 11
                   ORDER BY glt.Fac, glt.Yearz, glt.Period)
```

In this example, each record from the EntityTranslate2014 table is compared to the results of the inner query based on the predicate that Glentry.Fac = EntityTraslate2014.fac. Hope that's helpful.

For more information on Correlated Subqueries, check out the following link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank everyone for their ideas while I tried to get my query to work.  I ended up with following solution.  Note, for the sake of brevity, I only included the code for determining the Entity field.  It's not pretty and I'm sure it's optimal, but it works.

Thanks again for all of your help!!

```
CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT 
        BET.Entity 
    FROM 
        BET 
    WHERE 
        GL.Fac = BET.Fac 
        AND 
        BET.AcctEnd <> '' 
        AND 
        BET.AcctEnd = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GL.Acct),6,3)) 
        IS NOT Null
THEN
    (SELECT 
        BET.Entity 
    FROM 
        SOSViews.dbo.BI360EntityTranslate2014 BET 
    WHERE 
        GL.Fac = BET.Fac AND BET.AcctEnd <> '' 
        AND 
        BET.AcctEnd = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GL.Acct),6,3)) 
ELSE
    CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT 
            BET.Entity 
        FROM 
            SOSViews.dbo.BI360EntityTranslate2014 BET 
        WHERE 
            GL.Fac = BET.Fac 
            AND 
            BET.SOSDept <> 0
            AND 
            BET.SOSDept = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GL.Acct),1,4)) 
            IS NOT Null
    THEN
        (SELECT 
            BET.Entity 
        FROM 
            BET 
        WHERE 
            GL.Fac = BET.Fac 
            AND 
            BET.SOSDept <> 0
            AND 
            BET.SOSDept = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GL.Acct),1,4)) 
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN 
            (SELECT 
                BET.Entity 
            FROM 
                BET 
            WHERE 
                GL.Fac = BET.Fac 
                AND 
                BET.SOSDept = 0 AND BET.AcctEnd = '' AND BET.Acct = 0) 
                IS NOT Null
        THEN
            (SELECT 
                BET.Entity 
            FROM 
                BET 
            WHERE 
                GL.Fac = BET.Fac 
                AND 
                BET.SOSDept = 0 AND BET.AcctEnd = '' AND BET.Acct = 0) 
        ELSE
            'No Entity Translation'
        END
    END
END)
AS Entity,
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:  Although it may not be directly applicable to the OP's question, sometimes if there are too many rows in a join, it is as simple as joining on the wrong column.  This just happened to me....